# is it possible to go and install a suspension onto a bike that dosen't have any suspension?

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension, bso

I have a huffy 3.0 fortress mountain bike, I have to ride on some bumpy roads and trails, I have a friend who has a bike that has suspension. I rode it once and it was very smooth when I went over a speed bump. So I wondered if it was possible to install a suspension onto my bike. I tried to search it up, but I didn't find anything helpful. So I decided to see if any of you can answer that.

Comment: Certainly it can be done.  Rather silly from a financial standpoint, however, since a new bike would almost certainly be cheaper.

Comment: For the fork see:  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/is-it-possible-sensible-to-add-a-suspension-fork-to-an-old-mountain-bike
Adding a suspension fork, even if all clears, could change the geometry and handling.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a suspension fork (this bike seems to come with a very low quality one) or suspension seatpost or suspension stem.

On such a low end bike though, only the suspension seatpost would make sense -- for the other options, you're more likely better off getting a new bike.

Another option is to get the biggest tires that fit and run them at a low pressure, which should provide some shock absorption. But this bike wasn't intended for use off-road really -- just to be ridden a few miles on road.

Comment: The advantage of a seatpost with suspension is that it is easily removable and can be transferred to another bike later.  This is also a significant downside.   Plus the cost of a good one could exceed the whole purchase price of a BSO.

Answer (score 2):

You can but if it was ME, I wouldn't do it.

The fork would cost more than the bike is worth. You may be able to find a used bike that accepts larger tires at the or near the same cost as a good quality fork. I ride with a bike shop mechanic that has a bike with 4.25 or 4.5 + size tires and it is surprisingly softer on bumps than most full suspension bike. I rode it and was amazed. You also, have the added benefit of not having to replace expensive suspension parts when they wear out

Comment: True, but fat tyres are significantly expensive, locally double the cost of ~2" tyres.

Answer (score 1):

If you add front suspension you must worry about geometry and handling changes.
[Is it possible/sensible to add a suspension fork to an old mountain bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/is-it-possible-sensible-to-add-a-suspension-fork-to-an-old-mountain-bike)

A paralellogram seatpost is helpful.  Until recently, only Thudbuster was available by their patent ran out and now there is plenty of identical looking competition.

I was doing a lot of off road riding on a Surly Crosscheck.  I got a Thudbuster seatpost.  It helped a lot for the shocks on my rear end.  But it didn't help at all for the shocks on hands and through hands to head.  After about a year I developed a focus problem in one eye.  Got a full suspension bike and have never looked back.

Now I went the opposite way.  I put aerobars on the MTB, which is great for long distance mixed terrain riding, so that I can take the weight off my hands now and again on the road parts.

Comment: the reason of why i had posted this is because that it said on my bike "huffy 3.0 fortress trail rated" so i thought that it was a mountain bike, and it had oversized wheels. i think 2.0 and so i tried it and at the time it was good, but later i had started to notice, "if it is a mountain bike, then why dont i feel any suspension?" i checked out some other questions similar to this, and i saw the one where it told you how to ride without suspension, it kind of worked,